# Insert string after images on a page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, image

I have a bit of a dilemma where I'm trying to add 'figures' (numbers) to the end of each  tag on a page. With each image on the page, a new number is added which is 1 greater than the last.

So far, I've come up with a combination of PHP and JS, but JS manages to insert the number, and PHP manages to increment the number, but neither are working together.

So far I have this:

```
<script>
$('img').after('<?php $c = 0; ?><p class="figure"><?php echo ++$c ?></p>');
</script>
```

But, PHP being server-side, it doesn't seem to increment the numbers, for all images on the page the number is always 1.

If I use this without the JS, and just put

```
<?php $c = 0; ?>
```

at the top of the page, and then

```
<p class="figure"><?php echo ++$c ?></p>
```

Hard-coded for each image, it works fine, but I need a way for it to add it all in automatically after each  tag, and not always be hard-coded in.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need PHP here. You can do it all with jQuery:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var c = 0;
  $("img").each(function() {
    $(this).after("<p class='figure'>" + ++c + "</p>");
  });
</script>
```

[Here's the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yXjCx/)

Comment: Guys, thanks for much for this. I searched high and low everywhere for this, and now I feel a little stupid for not realising how simple this could be. Thanks again!